# Mounting host directory to container

Tags: docker, volumes

I am launching a container for my application. But my app needs few config files to login. Files are stored in host directory. How can I mount the host filepath to container?

**host directory** : /opt/myApp/config

**Docker command used currently :**

```sh
sudo docker run container -d --name myApp-container -p 8090:8080 myApp-image
```

Please suggest the changes in docker command to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `-v`/`--volume` key in such way:

```
-v <host dir>:<container dir>:ro
```

In your case it will be:

```
-v /opt/myApp/config:/opt/myApp/config:ro
```

You can use this key multiple times. You can also drop `:ro` part if you want directory to be writable.

See [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) on volumes.